# Forcing nodemailer to only do TLS 1.2 with recommended ciphers

Tags: node.js, tls1.2, nodemailer

I want to have my NodeMailer only beeing able to send to recipients witch are running TLS 1.2 - and only the current recommended Ciphers - i will provide the list.

I have looked at the current options and it seems like i cant provide this directly on the Transport? Or if possible how?

I have read the current documentation - and it refers to a TLS Socket Object, but i cant see any "require" tls options there?

Comment: Can provide a code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the TLS options to use then creating your transport (see docs here: https://nodemailer.com/smtp/).

The [TLS Options](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_tls_createsecurecontext_options) allow you to specify the maximum and minimum versions of the TLS protocol to use as well as the ciphers to use.

Setting the minimum TLS version to 1.2 will enforce at least this version.

An example is below:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "some-host",
    port: 465, // Use whichever port here.
    secure: true, // use TLS
    tls: {
        maxVersion: 'TLSv1.3',
        minVersion: 'TLSv1.2',
        ciphers: 'TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256',
    }
});
```

See the link here for possible cipher suites: [Node.js TLS Cipher suites](https://nodejs.org/api/tls.html#tls_modifying_the_default_tls_cipher_suite)